# How do I deploy an Act framework app to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, actframework

There is no official support of Act on Heroku, however the Maven buildpack seems to do almost everything the app needs, except start it properly. Any recommended settings and/or Profiles to start the app properly?

Answer (score 1):

The main two things to figure out were how to bind to the dynamically assigned port, and how to load from a different profile. This Procfile handles both of those things:

```
web: export act_env_http_port=$PORT && java $JAVA_OPTS -Dprofile=heroku -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.larvalabs.gifmsgbot.AppEntry
```

The environment variable that specifies the port is in a special (mostly undocumented format) that allows you to automatically override configuration settings. A tiny bit more info is the bug that contains the relevant changes: https://github.com/actframework/actframework/issues/636

Also note that I'm using a profile named `heroku` here, this is because I don't totally understand how the prod profile works yet, but I couldn't load settings from it when specifying `-Dprofile=prod`

Comment: You should use `-Dprofile=heroku` if you have configuration properties files sit under `/resources/conf/heroku` dir. However if you put your live configuration properties files under `/resources/conf/prod` dir, then you need to use `-Dprofile=prod` or do NOT specify profile as if no profile specified, then it default to mode (which is the `prod`) to load them.

Comment: Thank you. I found that when I tried -Dprofile=prod then I got errors about "Not able to determine where to load resources from." or something similar to that. And when I didn't specify a profile, it didn't load from the /prod resources dir. Are you aware of any issues there?

Comment: it should be /conf/prod, not /prod